# How do you center multiple textboxes in html

Tags: html

In the middle of the page is where I need the textboxes

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A magical thing called cascading style sheets

Comment: You have to use CSS. But explain more what you want to do. 
How many boxes ? How many lines, columns ? Your layout depends of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

horizontal plus vertical center is troublesome.

first center horizontally by making your parent `display: flex`

and include two bracketting children that stretch `flex: 1` as well as your centered element (this allows it to be a perfect third, if you want it to instead be bigger, remove `flex: 1` for the center child and put a width in percentage instead (pixel works but will not scale))

then center vertically by adding a margin top where you calculate leftover size :

```css
    .centeredchild {
      background-color: red;
      height: 20px;
      flex: 1;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: calc(50vh - 10px);
     }

     .centeringaid {
       flex: 1;
     }

     .parent {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100vh;
       display: flex;
       background-color: lightblue;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
    <div class="centeringaid"></div>
    <div class="centeredchild">hi</div>
    <div class="centeringaid"></div>
</div>
```

there's also the more common method : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center-vertical.asp

this website, by the way is full of usefull tidbits.

Answer (score 1):

Refer below code snippet to align your multiple text boxes in the middle of the page. (Consider page height to be 400px)

```css
.main-div { 
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-div {
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

input[type="text"] {
    margin:10px auto;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="sub-div">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this code:

CSS:

```
.outercontainer { 
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid green; 
}

.innercontainer {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="innercontainer">
    <p>This sentance is it the middle!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```